# PHP: Convert <ul> <li> Tree HTML tag to an array

Tags: php, arrays, jstree

I'm using jsTree and I need to convert this HTML tag tree code `<ul> <li>` to a PHP array.
The jsTree HTML tag will be passed to PHP to be parsed and store in a structured tree PHP array(see below for the PHP array structure).

*Additional question*: Is my desired PHP array structure good or you can suggest a good structure? I'm open for suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Cheers,
Mark

**jsTree Screenshot**:

[image]

**HTML Tree String**:

```
<ul class="ltr">
<li id="phtml_1" class="  open">
    <a style="" class=" " href="#"><ins>&nbsp;</ins>Folder 1</a>
    <ul>
    <li class="leaf" id="phtml_2">
        <a style="" class=" " href="#"><ins>&nbsp;</ins>Child 1.1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="open" id="phtml_3">
        <a style="" class=" " href="#"><ins>&nbsp;</ins>Folder 1.1</a>
        <ul>
        <li class="leaf last" rel="default">
            <a href="" style="" class=" "><ins>&nbsp;</ins>Child 1.1.1</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="last open" rel="default">
        <a href="" style="" class=" "><ins>&nbsp;</ins>Folder 1.2</a>
        <ul>
        <li class="leaf" rel="default">
            <a href="" style="" class=" "><ins>&nbsp;</ins>Child 1.2.1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf last" rel="default">
            <a href="" style="" class=" "><ins>&nbsp;</ins>Child 1.2.2</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="phtml_5" class="file open">
    <a style="" class=" " href="#"><ins>&nbsp;</ins>Folder 2</a>
    <ul>
    <li class="leaf" rel="default">
        <a href="" style="" class=" "><ins>&nbsp;</ins>Child 2.1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="leaf last" rel="default">
        <a href="" style="" class="clicked"><ins>&nbsp;</ins>Child 2.2</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="leaf last" rel="default">
    <a href="" style="" class=" "><ins>&nbsp;</ins>Outer Child</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

**PHP Array Structure**:

```
<?php
$tree_array = array(
    'Folder 1' => array(
        'Child 1.1',
        'Folder 1.1' => array(
            'Child 1.1.1'
        ),
        'Folder 1.2' => array(
            'Child 1.2.1',
            'Child 1.2.2'
        ),
    ),
    'Folder 2' => array(
        'Child 2.1',
        'Child 2.2'
    ),
    'Outer Child'
);

echo '<pre>',print_r($tree_array),'</pre>';
?>
```

**PHP print_r Output**:

```
Array
(
    [Folder 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Child 1.1
            [Folder 1.1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Child 1.1.1
                )

            [Folder 1.2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Child 1.2.1
                    [1] => Child 1.2.2
                )

        )

    [Folder 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Child 2.1
            [1] => Child 2.2
        )

    [0] => Outer Child
)
```

Comment: I.e. you start with a fragment of HTML and want to end up with a PHP array?

Comment: @Salman: Yes. I'm creating a jsTree editor with buttons to add, edit, delete, move, copy, paste and rename functionalities. After the edit of the user, I need to save the HTML tag tree structure. My problem I'm having a hard time parsing the string HTML tag and save it in a PHP array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding:

> My problem I'm having a hard time parsing the string HTML tag and save it in a PHP array.

I suggest that you use an HTML parser, such as [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). This will allow you to traverse over HTML DOM just the way you want.

Here is a quick and dirty UL walking script:

```
<?php
    require_once( "simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php" );
    $DOM = file_get_html( "test.htm" );
    $ARR = array( );
    function WalkUL( $ul, &$ar )
    {
        foreach( $ul->children as $li )
        {
            if ( $li->tag != "li" )
            {
                continue;
            }
            $arar = array( );
            foreach( $li->children as $ulul )
            {
                if ( $ulul->tag != "ul" )
                {
                    continue;
                }
                WalkUL( $ulul, $arar );
            }
            $ar[ $li->find( "a", 0 )->plaintext ] = $arar;
        }
    }
    WalkUL( $DOM->find( "ul", 0 ), $ARR );
    print_r( $ARR );
?>
```

Its output, not exactly as you wanted it but close:

```
Array
(
    [Folder 1] => Array
        (
            [Child 1.1] => Array
                (
                )
            [Folder 1.1] => Array
                (
                    [Child 1.1.1] => Array
                        (
                        )
                )
            [Folder 1.2] => Array
                (
                    [Child 1.2.1] => Array
                        (
                        )
                    [Child 1.2.2] => Array
                        (
                        )
                )
        )
    [Folder 2] => Array
        (
            [Child 2.1] => Array
                (
                )
            [Child 2.2] => Array
                (
                )
        )
    [Outer Child] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Salman. I'm currently testing simplehtmldom I downloaded in phpclasses.org when I read your answer. Thanks for your WalkUL function, it will help :) Cheers

Comment: I will just need to edit the PHP array structure to cater my needs. Thanks again :>

Comment: The only problem in the array structure is that if there are multiple same folder name then it will overwrite the array key. But I will find a way to put it in value instead in the key.

Comment: Complicated but possible. Your "child arrays" can be associative arrays: `array( "label" => "Folder 1", "children" => array( ) );`. Gets tricky!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of messing with html you should submit the tree data in a more programmer-friendly format.

```
$('#saveButton').click(function() {
    var treeData = $.tree.reference($('#sortableTree')).get(undefined, 'json');
    var tmp = serializeTree(treeData, 0);
    // now json-encode tmp and submit it
});

function serializeTree(nodes, parent)
{
    var parents = {};
    var childOrder = []
    var childOrders = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
    {
        var node = nodes[i];
        var id = node.attributes.id.substr(5); // assuming the id looks like 'abcd-ID'
        parents[id] = parent;
        childOrder.push(id);
        if(node.children)
        {
            var tmp = serializeTree(node.children, id);
            for(var id in tmp[0])
                parents[id] = tmp[0][id];
            for(var id in tmp[1])
                childOrders[id] = tmp[1][id]
        }
    }

    childOrders[parent] = childOrder;

    return [parents, childOrders];
}
```

Comment: Nice! :) A fast reply. You're good sir. I will try it now. Thanks! :D

Comment: Um I javascript alert tmp and this is the output: 
[{_1:0, _2:"_1", _3:"_1", _5:0}, {_1:["_2", "_3"], 0:["_1", "_5"]}]

I don't get it? Hhmm... Can you elaborate please? Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for referecence: there's also a jQuery plugin for serializing a HTML DOM Tree of <ol> and <ul> lists:
http://www.drakedata.com/serializetree/sampleTree.html - it converts a nested structure of <ol> and <ul> lists to a string which can be used as an associated php array.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a UL that does not contain any href elements (e.g. just plain text nexted ul).. I've adjusted Salman's simplehtmldom code to work with that:

```
$DOM = str_get_html( $catshtml );
$ARR = array( );
function WalkUL( $ul, &$ar )
{
    foreach( $ul->children as $li )
    {
        if ( $li->tag != "li" )
        {
            continue;
        }
        $arar = array( );
        foreach( $li->children as $ulul )
        {
            if ( $ulul->tag != "ul" )
            {
                continue;
            }
            WalkUL( $ulul, $arar );
        }
        $ar[ trim(preg_replace("#</?[a-z]+[^>]*>(.+</[a-z]+[^>]*>|)#is","",$li->innertext)) ] = $arar;
    }
}
WalkUL( $DOM->find( "ul", 0 ), $ARR );
echo "<pre>"; print_r( $ARR );
```