# Breaking down listed items from a DOM string into array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, dom

I have a formatted html string with some UL elements in it, and want to break this down into a php array.

Like:

```
<ul>

  <li>List 1
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>List 2
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>List 3
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What i am searching for is a solution that will get the first level li tags (including the content / structure in it) into php arrays. I tried .split, but its to fragile. Stranded at DOMXpath... Anyone?

Comment: Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817242/php-convert-ul-li-tree-html-tag-to-an-array. Hope this will help you to meet you needs.

Comment: Thnx, but also saw that question. Not exacly what i want. i want php array like:
$array[0] = " <li>List 1
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = '<ul>    
  <li>List 1
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>List 2
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>List 3
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes;
$data = array();
foreach ($elements as $node) {
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {  
        $data[]=$doc->saveHtml($child);
    }
}
foreach($data as $d)
    echo $d;
```

Comment: Thnx, but how to i access all the other listitems in the data array?

Comment: you said you wanted this result ,  $array[0] = " <li>List 1 <ul> <li>item 1</li> <li>item 2</li> <li>item 3</li> </ul> </li>"; its a string all together.

Comment: Ah, i see and, yes i did...  but what i meant is every  list in an array... so $data[1]="<li>List 2 <ul><li....."

Comment: Yeah.. that’s what i wanted! Thanks!